# How to put PHP variables in Div tag layers

Tags: php, html, echo, layer

I have problems putting echos in div tag layers..I tried many attempts to put  inside a div tag layer so I can easily move the result "name" easily on the page, so when ever it displays on the browser, it can be either left, right or center of the page. Before this, I tried to echo it in  HTML, but not working..below is my page script -- useracc-test.php

```
  <?php

//useracc-test.php
session_start();

// require 'lib/password.php';
require 'connect-test.php';
$userName=$_POST['username'];

//$sql = "SELECT name, username FROM users WHERE username = '" . $_POST['username'] . "'";
//$result = $conn->query($sql);
$query = sprintf("select name, username, telno FROM users WHERE username='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($userName));
$result = $conn->query($query); ?>

<?php while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
<div id="satu"><?= $row['name'] ?></div>
<div id="dua"><?= $row['username'] ?></div>
<div id="tiga"><?= $row['telno'] ?></div>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#apDiv2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 51px;
    top: 238px;
    width: 237px;
    height: 93px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#apDiv1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 344px;
    width: 234px;
    height: 104px;
    z-index: 2;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="apDiv2"><span class="error"><?php echo $userName; ?></span></div>
<div id="apDiv1"><span class="error"><?php echo $row['telno'] ?></span></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have missed closing of while loop

Comment: while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
{ 
?>
<div id="satu"> <?php echo $row['name'] ;  ?> </div>


<div id="dua"><?php echo $row['username']; ?> </div>
<div id="tiga"><?php echo $row['telno'];  }


?></div>....these are the echos which I'm trying to put inside a div tag layer so I can easily move it around.. need help...tqs...

Comment: I forgot to mention.. I'm a newbie.. a freshie.. please point me to the direction...on the page.. tq Awlad Liton..

Comment: while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
{ 
 <?php echo $row['name'] ;  ?> 


<?php echo $row['username']; ?> 
<?php echo $row['telno']; ?> } ?>

Comment: I tried removing the <div>like above.. but gives me error.. thats why I remain it there...I tried to put the echoes in div tag layers but not working...currently it doesn't have any div tag layers... coz I remove it..coz it keeps giving error.. hope someone can point me to the correct way..

Comment: The echos are already in the <div id> </div> but my question is.. how do I put it in div tag layers..like the HTML layers..where you can easily move the data around.. because currently it is showing above the screen..

Comment: name, username and telno are displayed..but it is showing above the screen... I cannot move it around..

Comment: 1) You've got a disaster waiting to happen, when you build SQL queries in this manner. Consider looking into either PDO or MySQLi (PDO is better). 2) You may wish to consider avoiding the mixture of html and php in quite this manner - it's often the source of hard to maintain code and hard-to-spot errors. Something like `printf("<div id='satu'>%s</div>", $row->name);` - What you want and what you're getting are not terribly clear. Changing your code to give the desired output should be straight forward, unfortunately I can't tell what that is from your question. (which you can edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the results showing in the body, thats where you need echo / output them. Just copy the block to the HTML body like this:

```
<body>
<div id="apDiv2"><span class="error"><?php echo $userName; ?></span></div>
<div id="apDiv1"><span class="error"><?php echo $row['telno'] ?></span></div>

<?php while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()): ?>

<div id="satu"><?= $row['name'] ?></div>
<div id="dua"><?= $row['username'] ?></div>
<div id="tiga"><?= $row['telno'] ?></div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

</body>
</html>
```